# Is the heart conscious?

Tags: neuroscience, consciousness

I have read that our heart can think like our brain. Of course it doesn't have complete functionality of brain but it has its own consciousness. Is it true?

Comment: Welcome to CogSci. What do you define as consciousness? Where did you read it? In short - no, the quickest proof being that a person after a heart transplant is still the same person with the same perceptions, feelings and view on the world.

Answer (score 2):

The general consensus of the scientific community would be that the human heart is not capable of consciousness.

The machinery behind consciousness is not well understood, of course, and there is quite a bit of debate, but [it is thought that some minimum level of complexity is required in order for consciousness to arise](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-theory-of-consciousness/). The human heart, while containing some neural circuitry, is very unlikely to reach this minimum level of complexity.

[Here is a Quora discussion that further explores this issue](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-neurons-in-the-human-heart-What-are-the-implications-of-this).

Comment: Yeah, it seems implausible for something with no sense organs, which only receives input from hormones and the "Vegas nerve" to have any real awareness, let alone be conscious. Can it respond to learned patterns? Possibly. Can it influence the mind and body with its electrical activity? Definitely.